# Is it possible to apply a function to a collection using Java Guava?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I want to apply a function to a collection, map, etc, using Guava.

Basically, I need to resize the rows and columns of a `Table` separately so all rows and columns are of equal size, doing something like this:

```
    Table<Integer, Integer, Cell> table = HashBasedTable.create();
    Maps.transformValues(table.columnMap(), new ResizeFunction(BlockDimension.WIDTH));
    Maps.transformValues(table.rowMap(), new ResizeFunction(BlockDimension.HEIGHT));

public interface Cell {
    int getSize(BlockDimension dimension);
    void setSize(BlockDimension dimension);
}
```

I already have an idea of what the `ResizeFunction` should be.  However, I need to **apply** it, not just return a `Collection`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Guava, you don't convert existing Lists, but instead create a new one using Iterables.transform:

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("race", "box");
final List<String> transformed =
    Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.transform(list, new Function<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String apply(final String input) {
            return new StringBuilder().append(input).append("car").toString();
        }
    }));
System.out.println(transformed);
```

Output:

> [racecar, boxcar]

Or, if you don't need a `List` and a `Collection` will do, you can use a transformed live view:

```
final Collection<String> transformed =
    Collections2.transform(list, new Function<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String apply(final String input) {
            return new StringBuilder().append(input).append("car").toString();
        }
    });
```

This `Collection` is a live view of the underlying one, so changes to `list` will be reflected in this `Collection`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about the nature of the problem (see above).  As you can see I need to apply the function to the row+column collections and I am not interested in returning them.

Comment: I accepted since this is correct, although I still contend Guava should have an apply() function that immediately applies to a collection.

Answer (score 3):

What about creating a function like this:

```
public static <T> void apply(Iterable<T> iterable, Function<T, Void> function) {
    for (T input : iterable)
        function.apply(input);
}
```

Comment: I would name the method `applyToEach`. And you can use `Function<T,?>` as the parameter type, this allows using functions with return values, in which you just aren't interested.

Answer (score 1):

Sean has already mentioned that Guava don't change the original collection, so you can't really "apply" a function on your existing collection.

It's not clear what your `ResizeFunction` function does, if you only changing the value of `Cell` in `Table<Integer, Integer, Cell>` then you can use [Tables#transformValues()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#transformValues%28com.google.common.collect.Table,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29)

Guava don't allow you to change the values of `R` and `C` in `Table<R, C, V>` (in standard `Tables` class) because those are used as keys while returning row or column map (`Table#rowMap()` and `Table#columnMap()`) and you cannot transform those because all of Guava's methods for transforming and filtering produce lazy results means the function/predicate is only applied when needed as the object is used. They don't create copies. Because of that, though, a transformation can easily break the requirements of a Set.

If you still want to do it then you can wrap `Table` object in your own class and provide a required methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think would would be better off setting up the table before population to be the appropriate size / have the appropriate number of cells even if they are empty. Something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++)
   for (int j=0; j<numColumns; j++)
       table.put(i,j,null);
```

This would ensure there is a cell for each position in your table. So long as you only add cells into row, column positions that are within numRows, numColumns you will keep a "square" table.